# Synchronise 2 youtube videos on Drupal site

Tags: drupal, video, youtube, drupal-7, media

I want to allow 1 user to point to a youtube video (possibly upload it through the youtube api) on a Drupal site.

And then other users can add videos linked to that video (separate nodes?).

The difficulty is that the videos should be synchronised. So when a user uploads a video to match the original one, he should be able to somehow indicate how this is synchronised with the original one. For instance 4seconds vid1 = 1second vid2

Any ideas, module suggestions, UI ideas are very much appreciated.
I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896430/keeping-two-youtube-videos-in-sync-with-each-other) on video synchronisation with youtube api, but I need a method that would allow the user to actually easily give in the synchronisation.  And then synchronise with different starting times.

Answer (score 0):

Best to create a custom module for that.  Give the user a form with the youtube id and a sync time then use the youtube api from there. No need for drupal specific code - tho you could create seperate nodes for each video, relate them with node reference fields and store any data in the variables table - butI'd probably create my own table for this.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. Though how would the novice users know the exact sync time. Any idea on how to let them get this easily?